# Boot Camp Assistant fails to partition on late 2015 iMac running macOS Monterey

Tags: bootcamp, imac

I tried for a good couple of months now to install Windows 10 using the Boot Camp Assistant on my late 2015 iMac running macOS Monterey 12.6. I updated a couple of times with minor versions of Monterey without any success. The Boot Camp Assistant always restarts the machine during the partitioning process, loosing all the progress. I tried downloading Windows 10 ISO from microsoft.com and left it in my Downloads folder, but it did not help as the Boot Camp Assistant appears to download a Windows ISO in the background. Please advise if I can manually partition my drive in advance of running the Boot Camp Assistant. (I tried in the Disk utility, but it allows only APFS.)

Comment: I do not believe the Boot Camp Assistant downloads the Windows ISO. The Boot Camp Assistant does download the Windows Support Software (which includes the Windows drivers) from Apple. If you wish, you can partition your drive and install Windows without using the Boot Camp Assistant. However, you probably would want to use the Boot Camp Assistant to at least download the Windows Support Software.

Comment: Did you use Safari to download the Windows 10 ISO from [this Microsoft website](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO)?

Comment: Thanks for answering, I used Chrome to download the iso to Downloads. As for BootCamp Assistant you are right it downloads Windows Support Software then it moves to partitioning. After choosing the partition size, during the partitioning process it always crashes the operating system.

Comment: Your current APFS container may have errors which prevent partitioning from succeeding. You can try partitioning manually. However if you succeed, then you will not be able to use the Boot Camp Assistant to finish the installation of Windows 10.